# Redact secrets/keys when writing to a file - Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to redact an api_key when writing to a file using dbutils.fs.put(), is there any way to natively do this?

The other option would be for me to manually remove the api key where it appears, but I'd like to avoid that for now.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?
Can you provide sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way to redact secrets/keys when writing to a file using `dbutils.fs.put()`. However, I have tried a workaround that you can use.
Is to manually remove the secret key where it appears in the file before writing it to DBFS.

I have tried the below example:

```
api_key = "k0u2bPJUpQ"
content = """
This is some sample content that contains the API key: {api_key}.
This is sensitive information that needs to be redacted.
""".format(api_key=api_key)
redacted_content = content.replace(api_key, "[REDACTED]")
dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/tables/file.txt", redacted_content, overwrite=True)
```

[image]

**Results:**

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  |
|This is some sample content that contains the API key: [REDACTED].|
|This is sensitive information that needs to be redacted.          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the above code the API key is stored in the variable api_key.
I have defined the content to be written to the file, which includes the API key.
I used the `replace()` method to replace occurrences of the API key with the string "**[REDACTED]**".
Used dbutils.fs.put() to write the redacted content to the file specified by the path "**/FileStore/tables/file.txt**".

Azure Databricks provides a native way to redact secret values that are read using `dbutils.secrets.get()`

Know more about the [get command (dbutils.secrets.get)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--get-command-dbutilssecretsget)